# How to extract data from Wikipedia for a specific category like Person?

Tags: python, database, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to extract articles from **Wikipedia** belonging to a specific category,for example company or person. Is there a good way to do this? Right now, I have a wikipedia data dump from which I can extract the page content, but I can't filter the data based on category. Also, can I get an exact number of articles from the wikipedia dump for the given category?

Comment: (1) please provide the code you were trying to write on your own; (2) What's a "wikipedia data dump"? In what format? How can one reproduce your question?

Comment: You question is too general to be answered. Here is an article of mine that introduces a library can scrap content from Wikipedia. https://towardsdatascience.com/three-out-of-box-web-content-scraping-applications-in-python-e342a6836ba4?source=friends_link&sk=8dc8dcab5f4eb76c41a47c7c86a35c04

Comment: @Roy2012 By wikipedia data dump, i mean the dump files which one can download from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/), this is a bz2 file consisting of xml document. What i want to do is the following: I want to extract articles which belong to a specific category like person or company. Currently, I am able to extract all the content into a txt file, but not category wise.

Comment: @Christopher I have used the ```wikipedia``` module which your article suggests. This module requires that I have the page title before I can get its content, which is not what I want to do. I want to extract all articles of a category all at once, instead of searching again and again.

Comment: Is the category part of the XML document you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what "extract" means in your question, but let's try to help.

If I want article titles, what I would do is to go to https://petscan.wmflabs.org/ and construct the query to tell me the titles. If I want content, I would then make a simple script asking either for the source wikitext, or using `&action=render`, one could download the HTML directly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&action=render.

If you want to use the XML dumps, there are several readers listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download, or you could write your own XML reader. If you run into an issue, feel free to ask a new question :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an SQL solution, you can find the articles of a category by searching up rows in `categorylinks.sql` where `cl_to=category_title`. It gives all the page ids of the subcategories, articles. Then you can count all the rows where `cl_type='subcat'` to find the number of subcategories. `cl_type='page'` give the number of pages.

To find the corresponding title of the articles or the categories, you can use `page.sql`.

An alternative way is to just get the `category.sql` dump. It has the number of subcategories and articles of each category.

The actual names of the dumps in the latest enwiki dumps would be:

- `enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql`
- `enwiki-latest-page.sql`